# Cheerio.js: $().find() promise rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to get child elements of a certain HTML class from a particular parent element using Cheerio. Here is my code:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(validHtmlBody);
var sections = $(".zloOqf").find(".fl").length;
return res.status(400).send(sections);
```

However, this code gets rejected with an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error:

```
(node:60502) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 1
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:208:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:199:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:717:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10)
    at index.js:41:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:60502) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:60502) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Putting this code in a try catch block and returning the error only returns an empty json.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your passing a `number` to `.send()`. This will attempt to override the status 400 and since it's not a valid http-status the shown error is thrown.

If your intent is to send a number, i.e. the number of sections, back to the client, you can send it as a string (express will automatically change the response content-type to "text/html":

```
return res.status(400).send(sections.toString());
```

Another possibility is to return a json indicating the number of sections:

```
return res.status(400).json({numberOfSections: sections});
```

Note: http-status 400 is probably not the right code here, as this would indicate that the client-request was incorrect ...